# Using functionality paradigms in reduce nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, functional-programming

I have the following problem, transform the structure below

```
[[1], [2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

by getting items from nested lists, as a result

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The simplest implementation can be written in the following iterative way:

```
tab = [[1], [2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
result = []

for x in tab:
    for y in x:
        result.append(y)
```

I wondering, how to implement following  functionality in paradigms of functional programming (for example using map). Any ideas? Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: how about: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))`

Comment: You can't use `map()` for this. It always produces the same number of outputs as inputs. You could use `reduce()`. The callback function can concatenate lists with `accumulator + current`

Comment: `[val for row in tab for val in row]`

Comment: from functools import reduce;
print(list(reduce(list.__add__, [[1], [2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9]])))